# Spring batch and xd good for data integration?

Tags: spring, integration, spring-batch

I have tried integration tools such as Kettle, and jasper PDI it is depend on ETL.

I have tried to use spring batch and xd as data integration too, its very nice. 
but there is no article discus about spring batch or xd  data validation (ensure consistence of data, avoid duplicate etc.)

I need some advice about :

1. is spring batch good tools for data integration?
2. if its good how the technique to do data validation?

Answer (score 0):

Spring throws error when something wrong happens with data read/write operations.

Then you have to think about the policy you want to make e.g. you may want to truncate-load.

What else do you want to ask, come up with a scenario and I will try to answer.